# Random NSLAYOUT Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

Out of nowhere without changing anything or uploading to a new version I can't build my app anymore because of some strange error which never occurred before in the past year and I see no way to solve them

[image]

I already cleaned my build, restarted Xcode, tried another test device, restarted my Mac and so on, nothing helped.
I even reconnected the outlet...
More over this error first only occurred on my real device, like 1 hour later also on any simulator...
Any idea?

Comment: Do you have another `heightConstraint` var? Somewhere in the same class or in its super class?

Comment: solved it by deleting all of them and attaching them again the same ways as before, now it works :D